# Database design for a video/dvd rental system, cant decide what to do, any suggestions or maybe alternatives?

Tags: database, database-design

The tables here allow me to rent one video, but i want to be able to rent multiple videos for one rental ID or in one rental record.

video ( videoID, videoName, ageClassification, genre )

rental ( RentalID, videoID, customerID, dateHired, dateDueBack, price, overdue(Y/N) )

Do I use something like a comma-seprated values for videos ID holding video IDs.

Or maybe having a a separate table called rented_videos linked to the rental tables, so there can be 1 or many videos rented per rental.

Or even an alternative solution.

Please pardon my relational schema, I am not a database expert.

Comment: It's likely that attempting to implement your schema and tacking the problems that arise would be better for your design long term then somebody telling you what to do and you blindly implementing it. Have a go then come back here when you have a specific issue I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely NOT use a csv list, this will make for ugly indexing in case you want to do a lookup for all rentals for a specific video.

The most common and clean way to handle this is to make an intermediary table with foreign keys pointing to both videoID and RentalID.
This should probably be the way to go for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. makes sense, I will be using your idea.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, there's no single right answer - but among the wrong answers, a CSV list is pretty high on the list!

Firstly, does the business treat a "rental" as a thing in its own right, or is each video rental a separate event? I don't know enough about the business to have an opinion - but I'm imagining the business domain has a "rental" meaning the renting of a single title, with a price and a return date (different videos seemed to have different rental periods - new releases 2 days, older movies a week; maybe there's a 'rental type' table in there somewhere). A single transaction - i.e. me going to the video store - would include one or more rentals, and each rental had its cost and due date; I also seem to recall the possibility of discounts if you took a certain combination of rentals.

All of this suggests:

```
Video
-------
Video_ID
Rental_scheme_ID
Name
...

Rental_scheme
--------
Rental_scheme_id
Length_in_days
Cost

Rental
------
Video_id
transaction_id


Transaction
----------
Customer_id
Date
Undiscounted_price
Discount
NetPrice
...
```

If this is way over-engineered, and the business says "no, we just want to keep track of who borrowed what", use your existing schema and insert a new row for every movie you rent.